# How to make a POST request using multi/form-data using Python?

Tags: python, api

I am very new with API things.

I have to make a POST request to API with the following "format"

```
content-type: multipart/form-data

Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename=""
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

Form data:
    file = file.xlsx
```

How can I perform the API request using Python?

Using requests library, can I perform it:

```
requests.post(
'api_url', 
headers = {'Content-Type':'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'},
data = {"filename.xlsx": open(filepath, "rb")}
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I prefer pool manager as this can manage timeout, retry, etc. easily:

```
import urllib3
from urllib3.util import Retry, Timeout
http_client = urllib3.PoolManager(retries=Retry(connect=5, read=2, redirect=5),
                                   timeout=Timeout(connect=5.0, read=10.0),
                                   num_pools=2)
data = {'asd': 'asd'}
request = http_client.request('POST', "http://localhost:8081",  fields=data, encode_multipart=True)
```

This will give you:

```
>nc -l 127.0.0.1 8081
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8081
Accept-Encoding: identity
Content-Length: 125
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=6ce0c07687204c761cc1e5a6d6f6046e
User-Agent: python-urllib3/1.26.4

--6ce0c07687204c761cc1e5a6d6f6046e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="asd"

asd
--6ce0c07687204c761cc1e5a6d6f6046e--
```

Comment: Hi Peter,

Thanks for you quick response.

And about the Content-Type ? Is it automatic to application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet?

Comment: Hi, no this implementation takes care only on request content type formatting (multipart/formdata)